# Python unit test assert fails by trying compare mock to string

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to learn how to do unit tests with pytest and mocks. I have this very simple use case:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from unittest.mock import Mock

class SFClient:
    def __init__(self, sf_client: Salesforce):
        self._simple_sf_client = sf_client

    def bulk2(self, query: str, path: str, max_records: int) -> list[dict]:
        return self._simple_sf_client.bulk2.Account.download(
            query=query, path=path, max_records=max_records
        )



def test_client_bulk2():
    mock_sf = Mock()
    config = {'bulk2.return_value.Account.return_value.download.return_value': 'test'}
    mock_sf.configure_mock(**config)
    client = SFClient(sf_client=mock_sf)
    assert client.bulk2('query', 'path', 1) == 'test'
    assert False
```

As you can see I'm trying to mock chained call to `self._simple_sf_client.bulk2.Account.download` but `assert client.bulk2('query', 'path', 1) == 'test'` is always fail trying to compare mock object with string.

```
$ poetry run pytest
F                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                [100%]
======================================================================================================================================================= FAILURES =======================================================================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_client_bulk2 ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_client_bulk2():
        mock_sf = Mock()
        config = {'bulk2.return_value.Account.return_value.download.return_value': 'test'}
        mock_sf.configure_mock(**config)
        client = SFClient(sf_client=mock_sf)
>       assert client.bulk2('query', 'path', 1) == 'test'
E       AssertionError: assert <Mock name='mock.bulk2.Account.download()' id='140589080832208'> == 'test'
E        +  where <Mock name='mock.bulk2.Account.download()' id='140589080832208'> = <bound method SFClient.bulk2 of <tests.test_salesforce.SFClient object at 0x7fdd73acdd90>>('query', 'path', 1)
E        +    where <bound method SFClient.bulk2 of <tests.test_salesforce.SFClient object at 0x7fdd73acdd90>> = <tests.test_salesforce.SFClient object at 0x7fdd73acdd90>.bulk2

tests/test_salesforce.py:27: AssertionError
=================================================================================================================================================== warnings summary ===================================================================================================================================================
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/salesforce-archivist-n3oqdCBe-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zeep/utils.py:1
  /home/piotrek/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/salesforce-archivist-n3oqdCBe-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zeep/utils.py:1: DeprecationWarning: 'cgi' is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.13
    import cgi

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
=============================================================================================================================================== short test summary info ================================================================================================================================================
FAILED tests/test_salesforce.py::test_client_bulk2 - AssertionError: assert <Mock name='mock.bulk2.Account.download()' id='140589080832208'> == 'test'
1 failed, 1 warning in 0.19s
```

I must be missing something obvious here. Why is it not returning the value I set when configuring a mock? Thanks

*// EDIT*

As suggested by one of the answers I tried also `assert client.bulk2('query', 'path', 1).return_value == 'test'` but it also did not work

```
$ poetry run pytest
F                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                [100%]
======================================================================================================================================================= FAILURES =======================================================================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_client_bulk2 ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_client_bulk2():
        mock_sf = Mock()
        config = {'bulk2.return_value.Account.return_value.download.return_value': 'test'}
        mock_sf.configure_mock(**config)
        client = SFClient(sf_client=mock_sf)
>       assert client.bulk2('query', 'path', 1).return_value == 'test'
E       AssertionError: assert <Mock name='mock.bulk2.Account.download()()' id='140508290106704'> == 'test'
E        +  where <Mock name='mock.bulk2.Account.download()()' id='140508290106704'> = <Mock name='mock.bulk2.Account.download()' id='140508282777104'>.return_value
E        +    where <Mock name='mock.bulk2.Account.download()' id='140508282777104'> = <bound method SFClient.bulk2 of <tests.test_salesforce.SFClient object at 0x7fcaa2b95150>>('query', 'path', 1)
E        +      where <bound method SFClient.bulk2 of <tests.test_salesforce.SFClient object at 0x7fcaa2b95150>> = <tests.test_salesforce.SFClient object at 0x7fcaa2b95150>.bulk2

tests/test_salesforce.py:27: AssertionError
=================================================================================================================================================== warnings summary ===================================================================================================================================================
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/salesforce-archivist-n3oqdCBe-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zeep/utils.py:1
  /home/piotrek/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/salesforce-archivist-n3oqdCBe-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zeep/utils.py:1: DeprecationWarning: 'cgi' is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.13
    import cgi

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
=============================================================================================================================================== short test summary info ================================================================================================================================================
FAILED tests/test_salesforce.py::test_client_bulk2 - AssertionError: assert <Mock name='mock.bulk2.Account.download()()' id='140508290106704'> == 'test'
1 failed, 1 warning in 0.19s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct code is

```py
def test_client_bulk2():
    mock_sf = Mock()
    config = {'bulk2.Account.download.return_value': 'test'}
    mock_sf.configure_mock(**config)
    client = SFClient(sf_client=mock_sf)
    assert client.bulk2('query', 'path', 1) == 'test'
```

or

```py
def test_client_bulk2():
    mock_sf = Mock()
    mock_sf.bulk2.Account.download.return_value = 'test'
    client = SFClient(sf_client=mock_sf)
    assert client.bulk2('query', 'path', 1) == 'test'
```

You don't need to use .return_value when using attributes.

Comment: While reading documentation on chained calls I saw this `return_value` everywhere and thought it must be used all the time. Thanks for help. It works as you described.

Comment: So if you want to mock a().b() (attributes of called outputs) to be the string "xyz" it would you would do mock.return_value.b.return_value = "xyz" . Otherwise you don't need to use return_value .